# чтение файла на стороне клиента

Tags: javascript, cookie, localstorage

Есть некое приложение, создающее на стороне клиента файл, и записывающее в него  одну строчку. Как можно средствами javascript эту строчку считать? Все действия должны происходить только на стороне клиента, без сохранения файла на сервере.

P.S. думала в сторону cookie, но не знаю, может ли десктопное приложение что-то туда писать.

Comment: Как запускается скрипт? Он вставлен в страницу или это серверный js? Если первое - где находится страница из которой работает скрипт?

Comment: эмм... немного не понимаю вопроса... Приложение находится на web-сервере, клиент получает к нему доступ через браузер, js работает на стороне клиента, периодически посылая и получая данные с сервера через ajax и php.

Comment: А вообще здесь происходит такая схема: на веб-станице, из ответов клиента формируется какой-то текст, затем он сохраняется в каталоге на стороне клиента с определенным именем(каталог указан в настройках браузера). Затем десктопная программа находит созданный файл и отправляет его на печать (нужна была печать без вывода дополнительных окон, средствами браузера избавится от них не получилось, кроме того средствами браузера не получается отслеживать распечатался ли файл). Необходимо по завершению печати вывести для пользователя соответствующее окно.

Comment: Раньше это отслеживание работало через  отметку флага печати в таблице БД (после того, как  этот флаг отправляется в БД, файл на клиенте удаляется), однако из-за проблем связи с сервером возникала ситуация, что файл уже распечатался, а окно не выходит, так данные о печати не пришли с сервера. Отсюда и необходимость того, чтобы данные о печати файла хранились только на клиенте.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге решила использовать  FileSystem API.
 Создав в этом хранилище постоянный файл, я могу указать десктопной программе где его искать на компьютере клиента (это мучительно, но все-таки возможно), тем более, если я правильно поняла, указать путь можно только раз(за счет того, что файл хранится в постоянном хранилище, удалить его сам браузер не может). Единственный минус - это  то, что такая реализация есть пока только в Chrome(((